# Remove dim screen when progress bar is shown - android

Tags: xml, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have an Asynctask that has a progress bar. I have created a custom layout for the progress bar but when the progress bar appears the screen dims. How can I remove this? Here is my code,

The Activity

```
 final ProgressDialog progDailog = new ProgressDialog(DashboardActivity.this);
            class loadComments extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, String, JSONObject> {
@Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();


                    progDailog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    progDailog.setCancelable(true);
                    progDailog.show();
                    progDailog.setContentView(R.layout.progress_circle);
                } 

                @Override
                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                } 

                protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {


                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json2) {
                    progDailog.dismiss();

                } 
            }


            new loadComments().execute();
```

The progress bar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#00000000">
<ProgressBar
android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

### Style.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="MyDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/orange_transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

### Your Progressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="@style/MyDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" />

</LinearLayout>
```